# Change plot title with variable in for loop

Tags: r

I am trying to change the plot titles as I output 5 plots in a for loop but when I try to assign `main = i` the title becomes all the values of the variable in `i`, instead of `i` itself.

my code looks like this:

```
x1 <- rnorm(20); x2 <- rnorm(100); x3 <- runif(100); x4 <- rnorm(30); x5 <- rnorm(40)
distributions = list(x1, x2, x3, x4,x5)
for (i in distributions) {hist(i, main=paste("Histogram of", i))}
```

So instead of the titles becoming `Histogram of x1`, `Histogram of x2` ... etc. the titles become the actual values contained in those variables

How can I make this right?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. The custom here is to give an example code that can reproduce the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you need to make the loop over the length of distributions and plot your histogram each time.

```
x1 <- rnorm(20); x2 <- rnorm(100); x3 <- runif(100); x4 <- rnorm(30); x5 <- rnorm(40)
distributions = list(x1, x2, x3, x4,x5)
for (i in 1:length(distributions)) {
hist(distributions[[i]], main=paste("Histogram of", i))}
```